# How to select columns in r by multiple condition (not using select_if)?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, tidyverse

Since select_if is `superseded`, I wanna know the "not superseded/tidyverse" version of:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2movies)
library(purrr)

movies %>%
  select_if(~ sum(is.na(.))/length(.) > .25)
```

Another option that works is:

```
movies %>% 
  keep(~ sum(is.na(.x))/length(.x) > .25)
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE? (data and desired output)

Comment: @AdamK `movies` data is from `ggplot2movies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `select` with `where`

```
library(dplyr) # // version 1.0.4
library(ggplot2movies)
out2 <- movies %>%
   select(where(~ mean(is.na(.)) > .25))
```

-checking with OP's code

```
out1 <- movies %>%
         select_if(~ sum(is.na(.))/length(.) > .25)

identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

`sum(...)/n()` can be `mean(...)`